# A Data Caching framework for Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, json, rest, caching, windows-phone-8

I've recently started developing apps for Windows Phone 8 (I have no prior native app development experience, I'm primarily a web app developer) and I have been looking for a good HTTP caching framework for Windows Phone.

I'm working with a REST based API which returns JSON data and want to incorporate response caching with different caching policies depending on the data.

I stumbled upon [AgFx](https://github.com/shawnburke/AgFx) which pretty much fits what I've been looking for but that was primarily for Windows Phone 7. I haven't been able to find something similar for Windows Phone 8, which works with the Portable HTTPClient library (I'm looking to reuse my code between Windows Phone and Windows 8).

I was wondering if anyone from the Stack Overflow community ever came across something which provides a flexible data caching for WP8, or if someone was ever able to port AgFx to Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is something similar available and it's from Q42
Take a look at the code here: https://github.com/Q42/Q42.WinRT

It's both for win rt and wp8

Also, there has been an effort to port AGFX to Win RT by Indrajit Chakrabarty ( twitter @indyfromoz ), but it wasn't as stable when I tested it...

Link for that here https://github.com/indyfromoz/AgFx

Comment: Q42.WinRT looks really interesting. I'm going to give it a look and see if it works for me. Thanks.